# Is there a natural math translator for matlab?

Tags: matlab, lyx

I was wondering if someone has used a tool that can write math in a natural way, like in math type or LyX and then translate it to Matlab syntax for easy function entering

PS I know it can be done in maple

Comment: See [LaTeX representation of symbolic expression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/latex.html) from the MATLAB documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Its called the symbolic math toolbox. [Here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/symbolic_math.html) is a nice tutorial.